# different style for continuous css class

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to have different css styles for a div that has same css class in a row and different for a single div for the same class.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve if the explanation is confusing.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  margin: 20px;
}

.number {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.number.bg {
  background-color: #e24381;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 24px 0 0 24px;
}

.number.bg ~ .number.bg {
  border-radius: 0 24px 24px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="number">1</div>
  <div class="number bg">2</div>
  <div class="number bg">3</div>
  <div class="number bg">4</div>
  <div class="number">5</div>
  <div class="number">6</div>
  <div class="number bg">7</div>
</div>
```

This should be the output:

[image: Output]

Can it be done by **CSS** only or does it require **JavaScript** too?

Comment: is it something you'd like to be dynamic? as in if you click on 1 it'll add the background?  Also, try taking a look at `:nth` selectors https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/

Comment: It should be dynamic. Trying to build a react component. Actually not on click but, when the 1 is passed as props then, it should add a background. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: I understood wrong your question so i deleted the answer. SO you want 3 different styles for 3 consecutive elements and for one element ( that is not connected to the previous 3 ) another style ?

Comment: You should add a class for example 'active', to divs you want to be highlighted. 
You will need some sort of Javascript since you don't know which one can be highlighted.

Comment: @MihaiT If it's just a single element like the "7", it should be circular border-radius. But if it's a consecutive elements ( like "2, 3 and 4" from the image, it could also be "1,2,3 and 4" ) then the border-radius should be as shown in the image.

Comment: Nay, no need for JS if static, Yay a need for JS if not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a vanilla CSS solution, you can use a *pseudo element* to do this for you:

- set `border-radius: 25px` to the `bg` element,
- fill the border gaps in successive `bg` elements using a *pseudo element* that is positioned *absolutely* and stacked behind the `bg` elements, and *shifted* using a *negative margin*.

See demo below:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  margin: 20px;
}

.number {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.number.bg {
  background-color: #e24381;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: relative;
}

.number.bg+.bg:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background-color: #e24381;
  margin-left: -50%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="number">1</div>
  <div class="number bg">2</div>
  <div class="number bg">3</div>
  <div class="number bg">4</div>
  <div class="number">5</div>
  <div class="number">6</div>
  <div class="number bg">7</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an idea using some pseudo element and without JS:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  margin: 20px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}

.number {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.number.bg {
  background-color: #e24381;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 24px;
  position:relative;
}

.bg +.bg:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  background:inherit;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:-50%;
  right:50%;
}

body {
  background:pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="number">1</div>
  <div class="number bg">2</div>
  <div class="number bg">3</div>
  <div class="number bg">4</div>
  <div class="number">5</div>
  <div class="number">6</div>
  <div class="number bg">7</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>If you want a dynamic solution you'll need to resort to JavaScript as CSS can only identify immediately following (`+`) or general siblings (`~`).</s> **For a really smart pure CSS solutions see the answers above. For the sake of performance they should be preferred over this solution.**

See below for a possible JavaScript solution. Instead of manipulating the classes as I did you could also adjust the CSS directly with:

```
number.style.borderRadius = `24px`;
number.style.borderRadius = `24px 0 0 24px`;
number.style.borderRadius = `0 24px 24px 0`;
```

```js
window.onload = () => {
  [...document.querySelectorAll(".number.bg")].forEach(number => {
    let next = number.nextElementSibling;
    let prev = number.previousElementSibling;

    if (next !== null && next.classList.contains('bg') && !prev.classList.contains('left')) {
      number.classList.add("left");
    }
    if (next == null || !next.classList.contains('bg')) {
      number.classList.add(!prev.classList.contains('bg') ? "round" : "right");
    }
  });
};
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  margin: 20px;
}

.number {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.number.bg {
  background-color: #e24381;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.number.bg.round {
  border-radius: 24px;
}

.number.bg.right {
  border-radius: 0 24px 24px 0;
}

.number.bg.left {
  border-radius: 24px 0 0 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="number">1</div>
  <div class="number bg">2</div>
  <div class="number bg">3</div>
  <div class="number bg">4</div>
  <div class="number">5</div>
  <div class="number">6</div>
  <div class="number bg">7</div>
</div>
```